# Failed to configure Secrets store IIS Web Deployment

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-deployment

Failed to configure Secrets store. This error occurred when deploying a Website on visual studio 2019 to local IIS server.

Configuring SQL Server Database dependency mssql1 in the project...
Installing NuGet packages to project...
Installing package 'EntityFramework' with version '6.4.0'.
Skipping package 'EntityFramework', same version or a newer version is already installed.
Adding TourOfHeroesDBEntities to store LocalSecretsFile...
**ErrorFailed to configure Secrets store**.
**ErrorFailed to configure dependency SQL Server Database mssql1.**

Comment: could you please share your detailed error message snapshot? did you run the visual studio as administrator when try to deploy site? you are deploying the site to the remote iis server or the same machine iis serve?

Comment: Thank you @Jalpa. I wanted to add SQL Server On-Premise as service dependencies, I specified connection string name, provided connection string value. Then I needed to choose where to save connection string value and l chose local **user secrets file** from available options. When finish is clicked, I got the error pasted above. 
Note: This is not a .net core web project. It's .net Framework 4.6.1 project using VS 2019.